# How to add several string values to textView with databinding?

Tags: android-databinding

I want to do like this:

```
 android:text="@{task.price, task.date, task.owner}"
```

(not with the binding adapter)

Comment: Try this:
    android:text="@{task.price+ ` ` + task.date}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
android:text="@{task.price.concat(task.date).concat(task.owner).concat(@string/myCustomText)}"
```

This also:

```
<data>
    <import type="String" />
</data>
<TextView
    android:text="@{String.format(task.price, task.date, task.owner)}" />
```